# Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp, .net

Прописываю строку в Package Manager Console, но файл создается не в том проекте, который нужен:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DB
```

Как указать в outputdir или другой командой, в какой именно проект добавить этот файл?

Comment: В студии в этой штуке `Package Manager Console` сверху можно выбрать проект, где создавать контекст.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать

Comment: На всякий случай [параметры Scaffold-DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext]).